# how to highlight top row in every excel sheet using Vbscript?

Tags: excel, vbscript, controls

I have a Vbscript code that generates multiple sheets in a new excel file. But automatically the last entry of each sheet is highlighted i.e. control resides with the last row. So for every sheet, one has to scroll all the way up. I don't actually want to highlight, I just need the control at the top. How can I set the control in each sheet to the first entry/row? Thanks for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO :) If you want your question answered you should really post some code that clearly demonstrates your problem, and try to tell us what you did, why, and what the outcome was.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt this **VBA** sub to your needs:

```
Sub JumpAndPosition()
    For i = 1 To Worksheets.Count
        Worksheets(i).Activate
        Range("A1").Select
        Application.Goto Reference:=ActiveCell.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1), Scroll:=True
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
' Assuming your Excel object variable is named 'objExcel'...
Dim Sheet
For Each Sheet In objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    Sheet.Cells(1, 1).Select
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using Excel and there is no reason to ask anyone these types of questions because you can record it in Excel.

Alt + T, M, R

then Home key then Up Arrow. Stop recording.

Gee look what Excel wrote

```
Selection.End(xlUp).Select
```

or if you had of recorded Go To dialog

```
Application.Goto Reference:="R1C1"
```

or if you had of recorded Ctrl + Home

```
Range("A1").Select
```